# Enter NewLine with JS in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, newline

I have 3 inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="id-1">
<input type="text" id="id-2">
<input type="text" id="id-3">
```

I have a button which calls a function:

```
<button onclick="myfunction()">click me</button>
```

This is the JS-function which gets called, it gets the value of all inputs and displays the whole value in a textarea:

> ```
> function myfunction() {
>   var x =
>   "MyText1: " + document.getElementById("id-1").value +
>   "MyText2: " + document.getElementById("id-2").value +
>   "MyText3: " + document.getElementById("id-1").value;
>
>   document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = x; }
> ```

This is the area where the functions shows the text of the input fields:

```
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
```

So far so good. The textarea looks like this:

```
"MyText1: input of id-1" "MyText2: input of id-2" "MyText3: input of id-3"
```

What I want to achieve is the following output:

```
    "MyText1: input of id-1"
    "MyText2: input of id-2"
    "MyText3: input of id-3"
```

My problem is, when I add `document.write("\n");` to the script, the page crashs with following console text: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`.

Here a working demo without newline:
https://jsfiddle.net/6nw8jrk9/

Comment: `"MyText1: " + document.getElementById("id-1").value + '\n' +` does that not work? `document.write("\n")` would write "\n" in the html and not the text area, that's why that doesn't work.

Comment: Sometimes I'm making myself a hard time, thanks -.-

Comment: use single quote  instead of  double

Comment: It's no problem, not one of us is perfect/knows everything :)

Comment: Notice, that if you're going to submit the textarea to a server, you have to set the value of textarea, setting `innerHTML` would send an empty textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a newline character (`\n`) to the end of each line when you build your string `x` like so:

```
var x =
    "MyText1: " + document.getElementById("id-1").value + '\n' +
    "MyText2: " + document.getElementById("id-2").value + '\n' +
    "MyText3: " + document.getElementById("id-1").value;
```

See working example below:

```js
function myfunction() {
  var x =
    "MyText1: " + document.getElementById("id-1").value + '\n' +
    "MyText2: " + document.getElementById("id-2").value + '\n' +
    "MyText3: " + document.getElementById("id-1").value;

  document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="id-1">
<input type="text" id="id-2">
<input type="text" id="id-3">
<br />
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>

<button onclick="myfunction()">click me</button>
```

Alternatively, you can use ES6's [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
function myfunction() {
  var x =
`MyText1: ${ document.getElementById("id-1").value}
MyText2: ${document.getElementById("id-2").value}
MyText3: ${document.getElementById("id-1").value}`;
    
    document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="id-1">
<input type="text" id="id-2">
<input type="text" id="id-3">
<br />
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>

<button onclick="myfunction()">click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess trying "<br>" was the wrong way! :)

Comment: @loyd no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

You should append `\n` after each input value.

```
<script>
  function myfunction() {
    var x =
    "MyText1: " + document.getElementById("id-1").value + '\n' +
    "MyText2: " + document.getElementById("id-2").value + '\n' +
    "MyText3: " + document.getElementById("id-1").value;

    document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = x; 
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add line breaks to your `var x`

```
  var x =
  "MyText1: " + document.getElementById("id-1").value + '\n' +
  "MyText2: " + document.getElementById("id-2").value + '\n' +
  "MyText3: " + document.getElementById("id-1").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break a line into an textarea with `\n` or with the HTML entitie `&#13;&#10;`

```js
var x =
  "MyText1: " + "valueInput" + "\n" +
  "MyText2: " + "valueInput" + "&#13;&#10;" +
  "MyText3: " + "valueInput";

  document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `document.getElementById("mytext").value = x;`

eg:

```html
    <input type="text" id="id-1" value="aa" />
    <input type="text" id="id-2" value="bb" />
    <input type="text" id="id-3" value="cc" />

    <textarea id="mytext"></textarea>

    <button onclick="myfunction()">click me</button>

    <script>
      function myfunction() {
        var x =
          "MyText1: " +
          document.getElementById("id-1").value +
          "\nMyText2: " +
          document.getElementById("id-2").value +
          "\nMyText3: " +
          document.getElementById("id-3").value;

        document.getElementById("mytext").value = x;
      }
    </script>
```